# Como usar o facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP, na qual preciso entrar no Facebook e contar o numero de likes num determinado *post* ou página. Gostaria de saber como incorporar isso na minha aplicação. Ouvi que deveria usar a Graph Facebook API. Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 - RTFD

Comment: Esse link me ajudou muito, ensina fazer uso via PHP e Javascript. http://tableless.com.br/facebook-api-sdk-php-na-pratica-e-preview-de-como-aprovar-seu-aplicativo/

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/products/ e aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins?locale=pt_BR

Comment: Para o que você precisa, acredito que tenha aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Answer (score 13):

Então amigo, esperei um tempão e vi que ninguém respondeu. Vou te ajudar, pois coincidentemente, eu tive que criar uma aplicação parecida a poucos dias.

O Facebook Graph é uma API do Facebook, para desenvolvedores poderem usufruir dos dados/conteúdos que são publicados/armazenados na rede social. Logo, é necessário segurança, digo isso por primeiro, pois veja um exemplo de requisição: `https://graph.facebook.com/{pagina}/posts?access_token={token de acesso}`
Sem esse token, você não consegue fazer nada.

Sendo assim, o meio de gerar um token é, acessando a [documentação de desenvolvimento](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/?locale=pt_BR) no subtítulo App Tokens, usando o seguinte código:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Obs: Sempre que esta escrito `GET` no início do código, significa que é o código para URL (possível visualização por navegador)

Logo, você precisa de um `app-id` e `app-secret`. Pra isso, você precisa criar um novo APP, para sua página ou que seja a necessidade, pegar essas informações e abrir na seguinte URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials`.

Veja um exemplo real:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obs: Deixei partes do código visível para ter noção de como ele é gerado

A partir desse token, você pode vasculhar todas APP do `dev Facebook`.

Mas vamos lá, veja esses exemplos, com páginas grandes pra ter mais graça.

`https://graph.facebook.com/9gag/feed` - 9gag = página;
 feed = conteúdo a mostrar (existem inúmeras opções, vide [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/?locale=pt_BR))

Mas perceba que não aparece o número de likes, por isso, você precisa colocar um filtro com `GET field`

`https://graph.facebook.com/9gag/feed?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)` - Agora sim, perceba que quase tudo sumiu e apareceu um campo summary (número de likes).

Caso precise mais informações, apenas vá acrescentando os campos com vírgula no links (compare com `GET` do link sem filtro), por exemplo:
`https://graph.facebook.com/9gag/feed?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true),name,link`

Tendo o GET, o resto é fichinha.

**Como pegar essas informações**

Na documentação existe os detalhes de como usar a SDK, no nosso caso, o PHP. Infelizmente tive um problema na hospedagem e não consegui usar a SDK, logo, eu tive que fazer uma pequena gambiarra pra funcionar. Segue a gambiarra:

```
$JSONcontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/{todo o GET que eu ensinei}');
$graphObject = json_decode($JSONcontent);
foreach($graphObject->data as $post) {
    echo 'Likes da postagem ' . $post->name . ': ' . $post->likes->summary["total_count"];
}
```

Não lembro se é exatamente assim na parte de likes, mas creio que já te deu uma base para estudos.